# Why trait method of sweebee/filament-char-counter is not found?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I added sweebee/filament-char-counter ^1.1.1 to my  filamenphp 2.17.17 app and adding HasCharacterLimit trait (my PHPStorm found it)  and using characterLimit method :

```php
...
use Wiebenieuwenhuis\FilamentCharCounter\Concerns\HasCharacterLimit;
...

class BannerCategoryResource extends Resource
{
    use HasCharacterLimit;

    protected static ?string $model = BannerCategory::class;

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-tag';

    protected static ?string $navigationLabel = 'Banner categories';

    protected static ?int $navigationSort = 1;

    protected static ?string $recordTitleAttribute = 'name';
    protected static ?string $navigationGroup = 'Banners';

    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\Group::make()
                    ->schema([
                        Forms\Components\Card::make()
                            ->schema([
                                TextInput::make('name')
                                    ->reactive()
                                    ->required()
                                    ->minLength(2)
                                    ->maxLength(255)
                                    ->characterLimit(255)
                                    ->unique(table: BannerCategory::class)
                                    ...
```

I got error :

```
Method Filament\Forms\Components\TextInput::characterLimit does not exist.
```

In the project I found file /vendor/wiebenieuwenhuis/filament-char-counter/src/Concerns/HasCharacterLimit.php with content :

```php
    <?php
    
    namespace Wiebenieuwenhuis\FilamentCharCounter\Concerns;
    
    trait HasCharacterLimit
    {
        protected $characterLimit = 0;
    
        public function characterLimit(int $value): self
        {
            $this->characterLimit = $value;
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getCharacterLimit(): int
        {
            if($this->maxLength){
                return $this->maxLength;
            }
            return $this->characterLimit;
        }
    }
```

It seems to me that I i have used tari in correct way, but why error and how to fix it?
I have cleared all cache...

**ADDITIVE INFO #1:**

I created custom CustomTextInput class and now using it error is not triggered :

```
use App\Filament\Custom\CustomTextInput;
//use Filament\Forms\Components\TextInput;   
use App\Models\BannerCategory;

use Filament\Tables\Columns\TextColumn;
...    
class BannerCategoryResource extends Resource
{
    ...
    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\Group::make()
                    ->schema([
                        Forms\Components\Card::make()
                            ->schema([
                                CustomTextInput::make('name')
                                    ->reactive()
                                    ->required()
                                    ->minLength(2)
                                    ->maxLength(255)
                                    ->characterLimit(255)
                                    ->unique(table: BannerCategory::class)
                                    ->afterStateUpdated(function (Closure $set, $state) {
                                        $set('slug', Str::slug($state));
                                    })->autofocus()
                                    ->unique(ignoreRecord: true)
                                    ->placeholder('Enter name of banner category'),
                                CustomTextInput::make('slug')
                                    ->maxLength(255)
                                    ->characterLimit(255),
```

But no any char counters are visible. I found file vendor/wiebenieuwenhuis/filament-char-counter/src/FilamentCharCounterProvider.php with content :

```
<?php

namespace Wiebenieuwenhuis\FilamentCharCounter;

use Filament\PluginServiceProvider;
use Spatie\LaravelPackageTools\Package;

class FilamentCharCounterProvider extends PluginServiceProvider
{
    protected array $styles = [
        'filament-char-counter' =>
            __DIR__ . '/../resources/dist/css/char-counter.css',
    ];

    public function configurePackage(Package $package): void
    {
        $package
            ->hasAssets()
            ->name('filament-char-counter')
            ->hasViews();
    }
}
```

Opening file vendor/wiebenieuwenhuis/filament-char-counter/resources/dist/css/char-counter.css I see a lot of css code - looks like it must implement
char counters functionality but how to  assign it to the project?
In file config/app.php I added :

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
     ...
    Wiebenieuwenhuis\FilamentCharCounter\FilamentCharCounterProvider::class,
```

and cleared cache.

Also I have

```
npm run dev
```

command running...

But still no char counters functionality visible : https://prnt.sc/WlIvJe17fuGN

?

Answer (score 1):

Your trait is used on current class which is `BannerCategoryResource`, but you are calling the `characterLimit` method from class `TextInput`.

Trait is used to add to the class which you want to add methods, in your case, the `HasCharacterLimit` trait should added in the `TextInput` class instead of `BannerCategoryResource` class.

---

For a simple example you could do：

1. Make a folder to put the class, for example I would make a  `app\Classes` folder.
2. Extend the origin class and add trait.

```php
namespace App\Classes;

// You have to use the "TextInput" class, replace to the namespace in your project below.
use Filament\Forms\Components\TextInput;

use Wiebenieuwenhuis\FilamentCharCounter\Concerns\HasCharacterLimit;

class CustomTextInput extends TextInput
{
    use HasCharacterLimit;
}
```

3. You can use this class (CustomTextInput) as the origin class and won't need to modify the original filement class.

Comment: Do yoy mean that I have to edit TextInput class ?
But that is original filement class. Have I to create a class which extemds TextInput and use it?
Could you please to look at https://github.com/sweebee/filament-char-counter/issues/1 branch ?
Which way have to use this plugin ?

Comment: @mstdmstd Yes, you have to. There a simple way is make a custom `TextInput` in your project and extend the origin `TextInput`, I update an example in my answer you can refer.

Comment: And I saw the package added the trait in the TextInput three weeks ago, it might can fixed the issue by update the package (`composer update wiebenieuwenhuis/filament-char-counter`).

Comment: Please read ADDITIVE INFO #1

Comment: @mstdmstd Use something like **Chrome Devtools** check if it render success or not, it render by [this line](https://github.com/sweebee/filament-char-counter/blob/master/resources/views/text-input.blade.php#L87), if not means your `InputText` doesn't have limit.

Comment: The package don't have document, it's hard to tell the correct way to use it.

Comment: What I see in browser : https://prnt.sc/nrIx9blrWlLy not sure looks like this php code is not loaded and css is not applied.
Does filament/laravel packages has some common way of loading package styles ?

Answer (score 0):

just place `use Wiebenieuwenhuis\FilamentCharCounter\TextInput` instead of `use Filament\Forms\Components\TextInput` in your Resource.